# Command a loop for Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, command

Is it possible to execute ping.exe file every 2 minutes one by one in a loop.

The BAT file can be  like:

```
programme.exe 
--server firstxyzdomain.com --port 4040
  RUN IT FOR 2 MINUTES
  THEN PAUSE 
  THEN EXECUTE OTHER COMMAND 
--server SECONDxyzdomain.com --port 20595 
  RUN IT FOR 2MINUTES 
  THEN PAUSE 
  LOOPBACK & resume
```

Comment: Please note that this site is not a free script writing service where you post a list of requirements or pseudo-code and ask someone to write the code for you! Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to lean [ask]! Once you have tried something on your own, [edit] your question and post a [mcve]! Thank you!

Comment: bitdraw, it was rude to change your `ping.exe` command to `programme.exe` after you had received an answer. Tell us what `programme.exe` really is, it isn't a privacy issue! If you do not do so, and you don't follow the advice in the above comment, you obviously don't want us to help you.

Comment: ok, I will take care of it. As you see I am new here. This is my second post in stackoverflow. I respect this community and I respect the rules. Pardon to not clarifying my above changes in time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Create a list of devices, ping them using the `-n` option as provided by `ping`

```
@echo off
:start
set "myips=localhost,127.0.0.1,google.com"
for %%a in (%myips%) do ping %%~a -n 121
goto :start
```